# mysql, 1 table with where condition joined with another table with different where condition

Tags: php, mysql

First of all, my apologies for crude terminology in the title.

```
<? if ($thisguy == "noob") { echo("bear with me"); } ?>
```

I have two tables:

one "**Ratings**" (rows: product, user, rating, added) WHERE `user = $thisuser[id]`,

and one "**Products**" (id, name) WHERE `product.id = rating.product`.

Ive read extensively on join (inner, outer, left, right...) and I am stuck like chuck on this.

I need all info WHERE `Product.id = ratings.product and user = $thisuser[id]` in an array.

I'm using this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ratings.product, ratings.user, ratings.rating, ratings.added FROM ratings INNER JOIN products ON products.id = ratings.product AND user = $THISUSER[id]");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $product = $row['product'];
    $user = $row['user'];
    $rating = $row['rating'];
    $added = $row['added'];
    $pid = $row['id'];
    $pname = $row['name'];
    }
print("$user, $rating, $added, $THISUSER[id], $pname, $pid"); }
```

This produces all in the ratings table (but only one instance) and nothing from the products table... I've tried this a 100 different ways to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Go easy on me. *winces

Comment: Can you provide your table structure along with relation between tables.

Comment: Try doing a `LEFT JOIN`.  Do you see all `NULL` values if you select columns from the `products` table?

Comment: @ naruto: i apologize. this is my first post here. i'm not sure how to provide a structure. the only relation is the products.id and the ratings.product

@ Tim Biegeleisen: I do. where it prints, i have all info but the products info. just empty space with 2 commas

Comment: @user3502802. I have provide with a solution try and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure the Database Name that you have provided in the query are correct since your description contains the table names as different from the code what you have made.

> Note: You have selected only the rating table alone and no selection from the product table and in my code i have selected the product name from the product table.

You have to use `ON` Condition along with the `WHERE` so that it will be perfect when you use `JOIN query`. Since the Syntax of the Join QUERY is resulting as such.

You can provide the comparison value in the ON and checking value in the WHERE so that your data looks crimped to what you expect.

The `JOIN QUERY` will look like this in your case.

```
$query = "SELECT rating.product,rating.user,rating.rating,product.name FROM rating INNER JOIN products ON products.id = rating.product WHERE rating.user ='".$thisuser['id']."'";
```

Comment: i got this to work! but it still only shows one result when there should be multiple. Is there something i'm forgetting?

Comment: In order to display all the values outside of the loop you need to store the value as an array and then you can print the variable outside the loop so that it displays all the value that is needed. Or else you can echo the statement inside the loop itself so that it displays all the values if it has multiple values too.

Answer (score 1):

You are not selecting any columns from product table, Change your select like

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ratings.product, ratings.user, ratings.rating, ratings.added, products.id, products.name FROM ratings INNER JOIN products ON products.id = ratings.product where ratings.user = $THISUSER[id]");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $product = $row['product'];
    $user = $row['user'];
    $rating = $row['rating'];
    $added = $row['added'];
    $pid = $row['id'];
    $pname = $row['name'];
    }
print("$user, $rating, $added, $THISUSER[id], $pname, $pid"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ratings.product, ratings.user, ratings.rating, ratings.added FROM ratings INNER JOIN products ON products.id = ratings.product WHERE ratings.user = $THISUSER[id]
```

Try this, use WHERE instead of AND in the last clause.

Comment: this only prints the $thisuser[id], all else is blank

Answer (score 0):

Be sure  $THISUSER[id]  contain a valid value.

try assign the var this way

```
$acc_user = $THISUSER[id];

"SELECT ratings.product, ratings.user, ratings.rating, ratings.added 
FROM ratings 
INNER JOIN products ON (products.id = ratings.product 
              AND ratings.user = $acc_user) "
```

and you can use an on clause with and eventually put inside ()

Comment: this only gives me the $acc_user id # and nothing else